# Oracle Connection Problem

Tags: 2013, oracle

My BDC list gives this error:

> MethodInstance with Name 'ReadList' on Entity (External Content Type)
>   with Name 'MaliyetVarlik' in Namespace 'BDC.BdcModel1' failed
>   unexpectedly. The failure occurred in method 'ReadList' defined in
>   class 'BDC.BdcModel1.MaliyetService' with the message 'ERROR [IM002]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified'.
>
> Correlation ID:9264179c-69b7-e0ac-af18-e5d5dc454a72

ODAC 64 bit is installed.
Connection string:"Data Source=ds; User ID=id;Unicode=True ;Password=password;"

Is this connection string true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this Blog: [Business Connectivity Services (BCS) with Oracle using Visual Studio 2010 – Part 1](http://sharepointjournals.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/business-connectivity-services-bcs-with-oracle-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1/)

Comment: I can see the columns now but there is no item. I think I can't get the datas.

Comment: It worked.. Thank you so much. I forgot an ';' charachter.